# How are we setting system.js configuration using angular-cli.json?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Previously we were using System.js for all the configuration but how it has been done in new angular-cli using webpack,I don't find documentation for this, can someone explain?

Comment: systems.js different and wepack is different for web pack can look at this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: I think my question is not clear, how we are using angular-cli to configure same thing that we used to do it in system.js? what't the role of webpack here, where can I get the meaning of individual property of the file?

Answer (score 0):

You may be searching for the **angular-cli.json** file